# How to write a script to detect the ssh connection to a series of remote machine?

Tags: shell

I am working on a HPC, there are many nodes on it. Using Interactive `qsub`, I can logon one of these nodes. And when doing parallel computing, I have to make sure how many nodes are currently connectable, and configure my program. Because nodes are often broke down.

for example, the node name are bh001,bh002,bh003,.....and

```
ssh bh001
```

will logon bh001 node.

So How to write a script to detect the ssh connection to this series of nodes? I want the script give a list of currently connectable nodes as a txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do something like this:

```
ping -c1 $server &>/dev/null && echo $server
```

That is, try to send 1 ping to `$server`, and if successful, print it, otherwise print nothing.

I could be wrong, but I have a feeling your system must have a standard way to get the list of nodes that are alive. Look in your manuals. It's an obvious feature, it must exist.

Comment: thank you! It works. And I know the admin have a command to monitor all the node. But I don't know whether user could do it or not.

Answer (score 0):

We are using 'nc' command to check ssh port for our centos/redhat base rocks clusters.

Normally nc package is available in DVD or default repository.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=192.168.56.1
PORT=22    
nc -z $IP $PORT &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    echo "$IP is connected"
    ## Do stuff for success  
else
    echo "$IP is unable to connected"
    ## Do stuff for fail  
fi
```

---